# How to update elastic beanstalk code with the AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, gitlab, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to do the deploy in the Gitlab CI, I already tried to use the EB CLI, but with no success. But I've found that the AWS CLI has elastic beanstalk support too and then I tried this:

`aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --application-name APPNAME --environment-name ENVNAME --environment-id APPID`

But this doesn't update the code like the `eb deploy` command do. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`eb deploy` is essentially a three-step process:

1. Zip up your application code and upload it to S3
2. Note down the S3 Bucket and key name to pass to [`CreateApplicationVersion`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/create-application-version.html).
3. After creating an application version, note down the `VersionLabel`, and pass it to the above `update-environment` call.

Comment: Nice! I'll try do this